# I have Some Problems With Using CSS With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a web page that has some dialog boxes. i made a blur background for these dialogs. it works fine until now. but when the user closes the dialog all my styles will get corrupt. for example border radiuses will gone and overflow:hidden doesn't works fine. why does this happen. and how can i fix this problem?

this is the code that opens the dialog box:

```
$("#faq").click(function(){
    $("#bg, #FAQ").slideDown(300);
    $("#b").css("-webkit-filter","blur(100px)");
});
```

and this is the code for closing the dialog box:

```
$("#bg").click(function(){
    $("#addtocart, #tamas, #about, #khabar, #FAQ, #bg").fadeOut(500);
    $("#b").css("-webkit-filter","blur(0px)");
});
```

another thing, when i use this code for showing the dialog box, everything will work slower than before. how to fix this?

this is the HTML Code:

```
<div id="b">
    <nav id="navigation">
        <a href="http://www.address.net"><img src="images/HSLogo.png" id="Logo"></a>
        <span id="Logotext">Store</span>
        <ul id="nav_list">
            <li id="faq">Item 1</li>
            <li id="tbm">Item 2</li>
            <li id="abu">Item 3</li>
            <li id="nws">Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>



    <section id="products">
        <div id="prdct10" class="product">
            <img src="images/10ditcb.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg 10d" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>

        <div id="prdct15" class="product">
            <img src="images/15ditcb.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg 15d" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>

        <div id="prdct25" class="product">
            <img src="images/25ditcb.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg 25d" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>

        <div id="prdct50" class="product">
            <img src="images/50ditcb.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg 50d" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>

        <div id="prdct100" class="product">
            <img src="images/100ditcb.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg 100d" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>

        <div id="prdcta" class="product">
            <img src="images/appleid.png" title="...اطلاعات بیشتر" class="bg aid" width="102%" height="102%">
        </div>
    </section>


    <section id="copyright">
        <p>Text Text</p>
    </section>
    </div>
```

thanks for reading

Comment: I think you're overwriting the CSS with the `.css` command, that's why your other properties are disappearing.

Comment: would you please share your html code as well? or better a jsfiddle!

Comment: i had no blur effect before. is there another reson for this?

Comment: Just an aside: when you want to remove a blur, set the filter to initial rather than blur(0px).  If you look closely, you'll see that Webkit renders text incorrectly (still blurry) when set to blur(0px).

Comment: @AminJafari & Hossein: Questions, answers, and comments on SO must be in English.

Comment: @simpe: That use of the `css` command will only affect that one particular style, not all styles.

Comment: Ryan Mitchell you mean that assigning the -webkit-blur to none will work fine?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree and am so sorry, but apparently Hossein can't explain himself quiet well in English! I just asked him to share the html code to make it possible for us to know the relations of those ids and what those ids are for if anyone's wondering!

Comment: ryan mitchel was right. thanks ryan. worked fine.